# How can I share Regular Expressions with JAX-RS?

Tags: java, regex, jax-rs

This is basically my `id` or `username` regular expression.

```
 @Path( "individual/{individual : ([\\p{XDigit}{8}]|[\\p{Alpha}\\p{Digit}]+)}/activities" )
```

What I'd like to do is create a precompiled version of `id` and `username` and then combine them with the or in the `@Path`, this way I could use the same pieces of regex in my model. I can't seem to find any documentation on how to add this in the `@Path`.

Comment: You don't! do your validations/dispatching for `{individual}` inside the controller

Answer (score 0):

You could go with something like this:

```
private static final String idRegex = "[\\p{XDigit}{8}]";
private static final String usernameRegex = "[\\p{Alpha}\\p{Digit}]";

@Path( "individual/{individual : (" + idRegex +"|" + usernameRegex +"+)}/activities" )
```